# Is it bad practice to include variable which must be initialised by subclass constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor

I've been doing a lot of reading on constructors and initialising variables, and I've came across a problem which I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to solve the lack of generics support by introducing a variable that needs to be initialised by the subclass.

```
<?php

abstract class Collection_Base {
  protected $typeOf; // Must be initialised by the subclass
  protected $collection = array();
}

class Cookie_Collection extends Collection_Base {
  protected $typeOf = 'System\Web\Http_Cookie';

  public function set ($item) {
    if (!$item instanceof $this->typeOf) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
    }
    $this->collection[] = $item;
  }
}

?>
```

So I was wondering, is it bad practice to include variable which must be initialised by subclass constructor in PHP? Is there anything I need to be aware of when doing so?

While not directly related, I've used the following sources to gather my information:

- http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.otherrulesandfeatures.classinitialization.php
- http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern

---

SOLUTION

```
<?php

abstract class Collection_Base {
  protected $collection = array();

  public abstract function getType();

  private function getTypeInternal () {
    $type = $this->getType();

    if (is_class($type)) {
      throw new \UnexpectedValueException;
    }

    return $type;
  }

  public function set ($item) {
    $type = $this->getTypeInternal();
    if (!$item instanceof $type) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
    }
    $this->collection[] = $item;
  }
}

class Cookie_Collection extends Collection_Base {
  protected $type = 'System\Web\Http_Cookie';

  public function getType () {
    return $this->type;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: I would set `$typeOf` using Cookie_Collection `__construct() ` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I recognized this as an anti-pattern, so I looked for where I read about it, but then I remembered it was this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super, which isn't quite the same thing.

On to what you are doing however. There are a lot of similar libraries which use a practice like this, however they differ by enforcing the practice in way of abstract methods:

```
abstract class Collection_Base {
    protected $typeOf;

    protected $collection = array();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        if (null === $this->typeOf) {
            $this->typeOf = $this->doGetType();
        }

        return $this->typeOf;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    abstract protected function doGetType();
}

class Cookie_Collection extends Collection_Base {

    /**
     * @param $item
     */
    public function set ($item) {
        if (!$item instanceof $this->getType()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
        }
        $this->collection[] = $item;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function doGetType()
    {
        return 'System\Configuration\Configuration_Element';
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this as the solution as it was the first to suggest using an abstract method which forces the subclass to implement, ensuring the developer implements the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Factory pattern to hide constructor details ... see http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Comment: Can I ask the benefits of adding a factory for this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

Make `Collection_Base` an abstract class and define a method that returns appropriate class name:

```
abstract class Collection_Base
{
    protected $collection = [];

    public function add($item)
    {
        if (!$item instanceof $this->getType()) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        $this->collection[] = $item;
    }

    abstract protected function getType();
}

class Collection_Cookie extends Collection_Base
{
    protected function getType()
    {
        return Configuration_Element::class;
    }
}
```

Using this approach it's not possible for other developers to forget about `type` "property".

---

EDIT:

Using a factory, as suggested by Luca Rocchi is also a very good idea.

Comment: This was one of my concerns, developers forgetting to set the type property. This solution works quite well in ensuring that they set it.